# Javascript scope chain

Tags: javascript, performance, scope, micro-optimization

I am trying to optimize my program. I think I understand the basics of closure. I am confused about the scope chain though.

I know that in general you want a low scope (to access variables quickly).

Say I have the following object:

```
var my_object = (function(){

        //private variables
        var a_private = 0;

    return{ //public
             //public variables
             a_public : 1,

             //public methods
             some_public : function(){
                  debugger;
                  alert(this.a_public);
                  alert(a_private);
             };
        };
})();
```

My understanding is that if I am in the some_public method I can access the private variables faster than the public ones. Is this correct?

My confusion comes with the scope level of **this**.

When the code is stopped at debugger, firebug shows the public variable inside the **this** keyword. The **this** word is not inside a scope level.

How fast is accessing this? Right now I am storing any this.properties as another local variable to avoid accessing it multiple times.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  _Especially this one._

Comment: This is not the place to concentrate to develop performant JS. DOM is slow, optimize your usage of DOM methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many good ways to optimize Javascript.

This is not one of them.
The cost of searching up the scope is *minute*.

In addition, you're misunderstanding the `this` keyword.
The `this` keyword is an implicit parameter to every function, which will either be the global `window` object, the instance that the function was called on, or the first parameter passed to `call` or `apply`.
The `this` object will refer to a normal Javascript object; its properties have no scope.

Comment: To show you just how minute this difference is: http://jsperf.com/javascript-scope-chain

Answer (score 2):

First, have you profiled your application and do you **know** that this code is a bottleneck?

There's no point optimizing this if your applications spends 99.9% of its time doing something else.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm just writing the code and wanted to know the best practice so I don't have to go back and undo a bunch of stuff. I guess it's not really performance related, but best practice.

I see some scripts even storing the this keyword as a local variable...I didn't know if there was a point to doing that.

Thanks though.

Comment: @Geromey: scripts store the `this` keyword as a local variable because there are inner functions that may need access to `this` from the outer function. That is because the inner function may be called with a different context, so `this` would be a different object when called.